# How can a certain Jenkins job script make sure that the master has certain/all plugins installed?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am having a setup where third parties will provide job scripts for Jenkins platform. When running them for the first time sometimes i will have non-recognized keywords of various sort. Often the reason is that of the hundreds of possible Jenkins plugins a few particular ones are needed but not yet installed. typically its a bit of guesswork to determine the truely need plugin and then adding it.

how can it be done to make the job scripts doing better in checking for their particular needs? is there something like a "uses plugin 1, 2, 3, ...", "if plugin 3 is not present then issue fatal error" or similar that can be added to the scripts so that they will instantly stop with a clear error message? are there any other means of smartly managing such requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly the answer you are looking for, but I believe that if you were to write your Jenkins pipelines in a declarative manner (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) this would address your issue.

A declarative pipeline would check the syntax prior to running, and if there was a call to a plugin that does not exist on the master then it would error out prior to ever running the job, which I think is kind of what you're looking for.